# Twilio Studio - How To Access Array Items From JSON Output of Function

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm calling the function below in Twilio Studio from a run function widget, then saving the EmployeeInfo to a variable setting the EmployeeInfo variable to value {{widgets.function_1.parsed.EmployeeInfo}} .  When I put the code {{flow.variables.EmployeeInfo}} into a say/play widget it will say all of the data elements but I'm having trouble accessing a single value (like saying a single Name).  I tried every conceivable syntax I could think of such as {{flow.variables.EmployeeInfo[0].Name}} and {{flow.variables.EmployeeInfo.Name[0]}} but nothing will play.  Do I have some syntax error somewhere, or maybe are you not able to store arrays in variables?

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  
  let results = {
                 LastName: "WAYNE",
                 FirstName: "BRUCE",
                 EmployeeInfo: [{  ID: 1, Name:"test" }, {  ID: 2, Name:"tested" }, {  ID: 3, Name:"testing" }]
                 };

  return callback(null, results);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just learning twilio studio flows as well and found that the systax is "{{widgets..parsed.EmployeeInfo[0].Name}}"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the values directly from the function response, not from the variable like:

*The values from the response are:
First Name: {{widgets.function_1.parsed.FirstName}}
Last Name: {{widgets.function_1.parsed.LastName}}
Employee Info:

1. {{widgets.function_1.parsed.EmployeeInfo[0].ID}} {{widgets.function_1.parsed.EmployeeInfo[0].Name}}
2. {{widgets.function_1.parsed.EmployeeInfo[1].ID}} {{widgets.function_1.parsed.EmployeeInfo[1].Name}}
3. {{widgets.function_1.parsed.EmployeeInfo[2].ID}} {{widgets.function_1.parsed.EmployeeInfo[2].Name}}*